# How to DRY a Rails 6 partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, partials

This works but I want to DRY up my form code.

/app/views/jobs/edit.html.erb:

```
<h1>Edit Job</h1>
<%= form_with model: @job, url: user_job_path(current_user.id), method: "patch", local: true do |form| %>
    <!-- contents of form -->
<% end %>
```

/app/views/jobs/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Add Job</h1>
<%= form_with scope: :job, url: user_jobs_path(current_user.id), local: true do |form| %>
  <!-- contents of form -->
<% end %>
```

/app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.user_id = current_user.id

    if @job.save
      redirect_to user_jobs_path(current_user.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @job.user_id = current_user.id

    if @job.update(job_params)
      redirect_to user_jobs_path(current_user.id)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

/config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :jobs
  end
  ...
end
```

I tried changing the edit and new views to pass the URL.

new.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {job: @job, url: user_jobs_path(current_user.id)} %>
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {job: @job, url: user_jobs_path(current_user.id, job.id)} %>
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(job) url: url do |form| %>
  <!-- contents of form -->
<% end %>
```

But it causes a syntax error:

```
Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check <%= form_for(job) url: url do |form| %>
```

In _form.html.erb, if I simply include the form using `<%= render 'form' %>` with:

```
<%= form_with scope: :job, url: user_job_path(current_user.id), method: "patch", local: true do |form| %>
...
```

editing works but new results in this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs", :user_id=>1}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

When I try `<%= form_for(@user_job) do |form| %>` I get:

```
"First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"
```

for new.

When I try `<%= form_with model: @user_job, local: true do |form| %>` I get:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/1/jobs/new"
```

which seems wrong because `rails routes` shows:

```
new_user_job GET    /users/:user_id/jobs/new(.:format)                                                       jobs#new
```

etc. I searched and most of the advice from several years ago is to pass a URL. I read the Rails documentation for forms, partials, and the blog tutorial. I suspect I'm making a really simple mistake.

```
<%= form_with scope: :job, url: user_job_path(current_user.id), method: "patch", local: true do |form| %>
```

Comment: `url` is an argument to `form_for` so change `form_for(job) url: url` to `form_for(job, url: url)`

Comment: Please read "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".

Comment: @theTinMan I've made some edits to remove code that's irrelevant to the question. Is that what you were hinting at? Should I make other changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a form that routes to a nested route you pass an array:

```
# app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [user, job]) %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

```
# app/views/jobs/new.html.erb
<%= render 'form' user: current_user, job: @job %>
```

```
# app/views/jobs/edit.html.erb
<%= render 'form' user: current_user, job: @job %>
```

But its kind of questionable why you nested the route in the first place as you're not using it as a nested resource at all. `GET /users/:user_id/jobs` should really show only the jobs belonging to that user and `POST /users/:user_id/jobs` should create a job belonging to that user and not the current user.

Comment: Wow, a 3 letter username! Thank you. I don't fully get what you are saying about nesting, but you might be onto something I should change. I guess because jobs is a child of user I thought it should be nested. I'll try changing routes so it isn't nested. Thanks again!

Comment: you're right, I didn't need the nesting. I've removed it and it works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** I didn't notice the routes.

You could create a `_form.html.erb` partial like this:
For nested routes you need to pass the `user` object as well.

```
<%= form_with(model: [user, job]) do |form| %>
  <!-- contents of your form -->
<% end %>
```

and change your `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` files something like:

```
<%= render 'form', job: @job, user: current_user %>
```

`current_user` since you're using devise

Comment: Hmm . . . I tried this and get:
Showing ~/git/EmpEmp/app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `jobs_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f49fc935358>:0x00007f49fc912dd0>

Comment: @max is with the right answer, I updated answer in any case. Thanks.